# Nginx killed for “Out of memory”?

Tags: linux, memory, nginx

My nginx has 8 process, each of them take about **150M** memory.

From time to time，my nginx get killed for this（dmesg）

> 21228 total pagecache pages 50 pages in swap cache Swap cache stats:
> add 85, delete 35, find 63/64 Free swap  = 2031300kB Total swap =
> 2031608kB 3407856 pages RAM 3180034 pages HighMem 290515 pages
> reserved 36448 pages shared 491788 pages non-shared
>
> **Out of memory:kill process 16373 (nginx) score 5013 or a child**

I googled it, turns out the  **Low Memory** is run out, so the oom-killer begin doing its job...

Here is my questions:

1. I get **16GB** memory, but the Low Memory is just **800M** (free -lm), how can i use the rest of them? google tell me i can use a patch **kernel-hugemem** , but it only for centos4, Mine is **centos5.2**, so...
2. Is it too much for a nginx process use 150MB memory? You guys never meet such a problem?
3. The Low memory confused me, 32-bit system can use more than 3GB memory without PAE, so why the Low/Hign memory for? Is not a kernel bug?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Memory management is very different between, say, FreeBSD and Linux.  Even the different BSD variations (FreeBSD/NetBSD/OpenBSD) have some important differences that can cause weirdness if you don't know what's happening.

Comment: Attach nginx configuration and free -m output please

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have a lot of free swap, which should prevent the OOM killer from activating but for some reason isn't. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/56874/oom-killer-killing-processes-despite-having-plenty-of-free-swap) from serverfault indicates that OOM with unused swap means the failed allocation was in kernel mode, caused by a driver that wanted a lot of memory. That might also explain why the free HighMem wasn't good enough to satisfy the request (kernel mode things can request memory from specific regions). You should look a bit farther back in the dmesg to see if there are any clues, like a backtrace.

As for the 3rd part of your question, there is a distinction between HighMen and LowMem when using PAE because it extends the physical address space to 36 bits while the virtual address space is still 32 bits. Access to the full potential 64G of physical addresses can't be done as quickly as access to a fixed 4G subset, so the kernel divides the memory up and tries to keep the most performance-critical things in the "low" area.

Comment: Thx, i agree with you about the **keep the most performance-critical things in the "low" area** part, but my free -m output like this:

Comment: total       used       free
Mem:         12177       1737      10439
Low:           780        263        516

The Low area shouldn't be about 4*1024MB here?